# How to avoid factors in R when reading csv data

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have data in a csv file. when i get it read, the columns are in factor levels using which I cannot do any computation.

I used 
`as.numeric(df$variablename)` but it renders a completely different set of data for the variable.

```
original data in the variable: 2961,488,632,
   as.numeric output: 1,8,16
```

Comment: I think you are missing some steps here.  Can you please show us how you are reading in the csv file?  Are you using read.csv?  Are the numbers definitely unquoted? Is it possible that some where in the data there are characters?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [read.table reads numbers as factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874293/read-table-reads-numbers-as-factors). The issue is not that there are too many digits. Instead, either some of the numbers are quoted, or (more likely) there are non-numeric values in the column causing R to coerce the entire column into character strings. I recommend reopening, or at least finding a more appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @gersht is likely correct -- the data probably have some symbol that is not `NA` representing missing or if they were manually entered, some records were entered as strings.

Comment: Ugh I wrote a long answer and can't post it.  Short version, read it in, use skimr::skim to inspect the data,  interatively process.

Comment: Since it's a question of data types, it's important to have a sample of that data in its actual types, such as from `dput`. Without that, it's hard to know what the question is a dupe of—just a guessing game of incorrectly encoded data.

Answer (score 5):

When reading data using `read.table` you can

- specify how your data is separated `sep =` ,
- what the decimal point is `dec =` ,
- how `NA` characters look like `na.strings =`
- that you do not want to convert strings to factors `stringsAsFactors = F`

In your case you could use something like:

```
read.table("mycsv.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".", stringsAsFactors = F,
            na.strings = c("", "-"))
```

Comment: R imports **strings** as factors, so the issue isn't the fact that the column is being imported as a factor, it's that numbers are being interpreted as strings, perhaps because of unusual missing values. In that case something like `read.csv("file.csv", na.strings = c("nan", "-"))` would be more appropriate.

Comment: It's hard to say for certain without more details from the OP, but I think it's highly unlikely that the decimal is the culprit. There are only a couple flavors of CSV, and apparently R has correctly recognized the delimiter. It the decimal is causing the issue then it must be something exotic and not `,` or `.`. Also, the example values are integers.

Comment: I've removed the downvote because you added `na.strings`, and the OP's question is missing important details, so it's difficult to give a precise answer.

Comment: @Cettt  I would add that in a large data set where he can't easily visually scan, OP should read in the data and then potentially run a table() to find the nonconforming cases.

Comment: @Elin For now the question is closed anyways. Until further input from the OP I would leave my answer as it is now

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer by Cettt , there's also `colClasses`.

If you know in advance what data types the columns your csv file has, you can specify this. This stops R from "guessing" what the datatype is, and lets you know when something isn't right, rather than deciding it must be a string. e.g. if your 4-column csv file has columns that are Text, Factors, Integer, Numeric, you can use

```
read.table("mycsv.csv", header = T, sep = ",", dec = ".", 
    colClasses=c("character", "factor", "integer", "numeric"))
```

### Edited to add:

As pointed out by gersht, the issue is likely some non-number in the numbers column. Often, this can be how the value NA was coded. Specifying `colClasses` causes R to give an error message when it encounters any such "not numeric or NA" values, so you can easily see the issue. If it's a non-default coding of NA, use the argument `na.strings = c("NA", "YOUR NA VALUE")` If it's another issue, you'll likely have to fix the file before importing. For example:

```
read.table(sep=",", 
           colClasses=c("character", "numeric"), 
           text="
           cat,11
           canary,12
           dog,1O")  # NB not a 10; it's a 1 and a capital-oh.
```

gives

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     scan() expected 'a real', got '1O'

Comment: R imports **strings** as factors, so the issue isn't the fact that the column is being imported as a factor, it's that numbers are being interpreted as strings, perhaps because of unusual missing values. In that case something like `read.csv("file.csv", na.strings = c("nan", "-"))` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Whatever is making `read.table` think numbers are strings will be flagged with an error message by specifying colClasses. Then we won't have to guess what's in the OP's file; R will helpfully tell the OP what it found that wasn't a number.